# page not found when serving static files via django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, file, django-staticfiles

so in settings.py I have

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

and also

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'myapp.apps.MyappConfig'
]
```

hence as you can see django.contrib.staticfiles is there and moreover Debug = True

and in my app directory I have a file existing in this path

```
myapp/static/css/myapp.css
```

However, when I go to http://localhost/myapp/static/css/myapp.css

it ends up returning

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method:     GET
```

what am I doing wrong and how can I get django to serve static files properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include this in your project/urls.py

```
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the option [STATICFILES_DIRS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#std:setting-STATICFILES_DIRS) in your settings.

An example:

```
# settings.py
...
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    "/path/to/your/static/files/folder",
]
...
```

In your templates, use the static template tag like

```
# some_page.html
...
{% load static %}
<img src="{% static "my_app/example.jpg" %}" alt="My image"/>
...
```

or hard-code like

```
# some_page.html
...
<img src="/static/my_app/example.jpg" alt="My image"/>
...
```